# Should a logger be injected into the constructor?

Tags: logging, dependency-injection

I am trying to better understand the Dependency Injection pattern, and I came to the question whether a logger should be injected or not.

The language I am using is Python, but the concept is agnostic. What I do have now is just an import of a singleton logger module into the scope, and call it whenever necessary. As for example:

```
import logger

class Television(object):

     def __init__(self, colour, inches):
          self._colour = colour
          self._inches = inches

     def turn_on(self):
          # do something
          logger.message('TV has been turned on')
```

If I was using dependency injection, I would do something like this:

```
import logger

class Television(object):

     def __init__(self, colour, inches, logger):
          self._colour = colour
          self._inches = inches
          self._logger = logger

     def turn_on(self):
          # do something
          self._logger.message('TV has been turned on')
```

Which makes the code more testeable (although python is so dynamic that while testing you could just mock on-the-fly the logger in the module).

The drawback is that I have to take care of the injection by using alternative constructors, some injection framework or service locator. I am not quite sure if the effort does pay off or not.

I've seen other similar questions, but I couldn't really understand them, or the answers did not satisfy me:

[Is it a good practice to have logger as a singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472678/is-it-a-good-practice-to-have-logger-as-a-singleton)

[Dependency injection and named loggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452318/dependency-injection-and-named-loggers)

[Should a Python logger be passed as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052778/should-a-logger-be-passed-as-parameter)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892137/windsor-pulling-transient-objects-from-the-container

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7906547/126014

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1709048/126014

Comment: @bgusach The question is poorly phrased because the answer can vary by the language. It would've helped if it was limited to Python only. You yourself noted that Python is dynamic.